# EBSapps.env file not found

Tags: oracle

hi I am trying to install oracle e business suit 12.2.12 virtual machine on oracle vm and did every step except run "(EPSapps.env") file and it gives me `no such file` and when trying to list directories in scripts directory. I find the file name but in white color not green and not working. How can I find or create this file

find location file and run it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.